# Service does not start at boot time

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, systemctl

I am running a Flask application on my RPi successfully by issuing the following command

```
export FLASK_APP=/opt/fzwk-access-source/app.py && flask run --host 0.0.0.0
```

Now, my next goal is naturally to run the Flask application when booting up the RPi. To do so, I created the service `/etc/systemd/system/fzwk-access.service`, which looks as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=fzwk-access
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/opt/fzwk-access-source
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "export FLASK_APP=/opt/fzwk-access-source/app.py && flask run --host 0.0.0.0"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

`ls -la` provides me with the following:

```
...
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  2 12:41 dhcpcd.service.d
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Dec  2 12:41 dhcpcd5.service -> /lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service
4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  312 Mar  1 17:12 fzwk-access.service
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  2 12:37 getty.target.wants
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  2 12:39 getty@tty1.service.d
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  2 12:40 halt.target.wants
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 18 07:38 multi-user.target.wants
...
```

With that in place, I can start the service with the command

```
sudo systemctl start fzwk-access
```

successfully. I have thus enabled the service with

```
sudo systemctl enable fzwk-access
```

My expectation now is that after a reboot the service is starting successfully, but it does not.

`sudo systemctl status fzwk-access` shows the following:

```
● fzwk-access.service - fzwk-access
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/fzwk-access.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Clearly, I am missing something here – I cannot figure out what it is...

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [raspberrypi.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, have moved my question.